# Programmatically storing authentication object

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to create a usernamepasswordauthenticationtoken and directly add into the security context. At many place I have read the below code works:

```
Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( username, password );
Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate( request );
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication( result );
```

But for me I need to add below mentioned lines to make it work

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because I don't want to use sessions.

Comment: What do you mean by "make it work"? What is your use case?

Comment: 1.I want to programatically insert user into spring security context(i.e not from login page I will directly create a usernamepasswordauthentication token and add it into context.)
2. I want to avoid sessions.

But when I try only first 3 lines of code it doesnt work for me. Spring redirects me to the login page i.e user doesnot get stored in the security context.But when I add object in session it works. So I want to know is there any way to avoid using sessions in spring security?

Comment: Spring Security web infrastructure is based on Servlet Filters and a bunch of helper classes. It can be easily extended to meet almost any use case via its extension points. What you need is to find the right extension point for you. Please post your Spring Security configuration. You do not have to use session but then you have to store the authentication details somewhere else (e.g. database) or authenticate user with every request.

Comment: If you don't use a session, then there is nowhere for the state to be stored between requests. How do you expect the server to know that a later request is from the same user? You should also post your security configuration. Just adding the first few lines to an app is dangerous unless you make sure the context is also cleared at the end of a request.